# How to connect Spring Boot Application with HFSQL database?

Tags: java, database

i am a beginner in programming, i am trying to get the data from hfsql database in my spring boot project, the official website of hfsql says it is possible by using ODBC but java says its not possible to use ODBC after java8,
any ideas please?
thanks

Comment: u can check this article and give it a try with spring after getting the database driver and putting it in the class path (u can pull it through maven) then provide all the needed info (db info) to spring through application.properties file.
https://help.windev.com/en-US/?3044273&name=using_odbc_hfsql_classic_via_jdbc

Comment: thank you for your reply, the article is using JdbcOdbcDriver which is no longer supported in java